# Repeat the Column values for the key multiple times in SQL SAP hana

Tags: sql, hana

I have a table with a key and 9 columns (say A) other tables with only a key (say B), now I have to join table A with B on the key and repeat that 9 columns 30 times. can someone suggest some ideas?

just join can be done if only 9 columns have to be attached but the problem is I have to attach 30 times.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  It is unclear what you want the results to look like.

Comment: What is the issue just repeating that columns as many times as you need? Also result set should have unique column names, so you need to provide aliases for new columns.

Comment: @astentx Tables/queries & result sets do not need unique column names.

Comment: @philipxy Tables in SQL definitely shoud have unique names. Resultsets may contain repeated names since you can access columns positionally, I was not accurate here. But if this need to be consumed in SQL queries (via view or subquery), it should have unique names (and it also makes query more readable).

Comment: @astentx The language is defined how it's defined. If you're going to use "should", (try to) define just what you mean by it.